# Use super method with sub type param

Tags: scala, inheritance, covariance, contravariance, subtyping

I'm trying to implement some function in a super class so I don't have to always repeat it in its children. Sample:

```scala
trait Animal {
  def applyF(transition: Animal => Animal): Animal = transition(this) // Animal as param and return type
}
case class Cat(color: String) extends Animal {
  def changeColor(color: String): Cat = this.copy(color)

  def update(): Animal = {
    val transition = (cat: Cat) => cat.changeColor("yellow") // Cat as param and return type
    applyF(transition) // <-- Type mismatch, expected: Animal => Animal, actual: Cat => Cat
  }
}
```

But this gives a type mismatch because `Cat` is not `Animal`. Why does this not work?
Cat extends Animal so it should be an animal right?

Has this something to do with co-/contravariant?

How can I fix it?

----- Update -----

Second example:

```scala
trait Animal {
  def applyF[A >: this.type <: Animal](transitions: Iterable[A => Animal]): Animal =
    transitions.foldLeft(this)((animal, transition) => transition(animal))
}
case class Cat(color: String) extends Animal {
  def changeColor(color: String): Cat = this.copy(color)

  def update(): Animal = {
    val transition = (cat: Cat) => cat.changeColor("yellow") // Cat as param and return type
    applyF(Iterable(transition)) // <-- Type mismatch, expected: A, actual: entity.type (with underlying type example.state.Entity)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Cat` extends `Animal` but `Cat => Cat` doesn't extend `Animal => Animal`.

`A => B` is covariant with respect to `B` and contravariant with respect to `A`, i.e. if `A1 <: A`, `B1 <: B` then `A => B1 <: A => B <: A1 => B`.

What if you parametrize `Animal#applyF`?

```
trait Animal {
  def applyF[A >: this.type <: Animal](transition: A => Animal): Animal = transition(this)
}
```

---

```
trait Animal { 
  def applyF[A >: this.type <: Animal](transitions: Iterable[A => A]): Animal /*A*/ =
    transitions.foldLeft[A](this)((animal, transition) => transition(animal)) 
}
```

Comment: Nice this works. Thanks for your fast answer. Do you have a solution for the second example I've just added with the Iterable[A => Animal] example?

Comment: @Piu130 Try `trait Animal {
    def applyF[A >: this.type <: Animal](transitions: Iterable[A => A]): Animal /*A*/ =
      transitions.foldLeft[A](this)((animal, transition) => transition(animal))
  }` if this is enough.

Comment: This works. Could you add it to the answer? Do you think this is good code?

Comment: @Piu130 Added. It's ok.

Answer (score 1):

Other option would be to use [**F-Bounded Polymorphism**](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html#fbounded).

```
trait Animal[A <: Animal[A]] { self: A =>
  def applyF(transition: Iterable[A => A]): A = // I would use List instead of Iterable.
    transition.foldLeft(this)((animal, transition) => transition(animal))
}
final case class Cat(color: String) extends Animal[Cat] {
  def changeColor(color: String): Cat = this.copy(color)

  def update(): Cat =
    applyF(List(cat => cat.changeColor("yellow")))
}
```

However, keep in mind that [it does bring its own problems](https://tpolecat.github.io/2015/04/29/f-bounds.html).

Comment: Nice links. Thanks. It looks like there is no beauty way to fix the problem.

Comment: @Piu130 does your transitions will return always the same kind of `Animal`? or can they change the type?

Comment: It returns always the same Animal.